# How to create Custom Textarea using html and jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css, responsive-design, textarea

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("textarea").on('keydown keypress keyup', function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
         return true;
      }
      var maxRowCount = $(this).attr("rows") || 4;
      var lineCount = $(this).val().split('\n').length;
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
         if (lineCount == maxRowCount) {
            return false;
         }
      }
      var jsElement = $(this)[0];
      if (jsElement.clientHeight < jsElement.scrollHeight) {
         var text = $(this).val();
         text = text.slice(0, -1);
         $(this).val(text);
         return false;
      }

   });
   });
```

```css
h1 { color:#fff;}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
```

In the above code, I am able to enter only 5 times, then after that it shows an error message. It means no extra row add on enter and not to set character limit. [if textarea field with text and tried to enter character 2nd or 3rd line thenor last line then it remove character automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIbXs.png)

Comment: Any kind of help will be appreciable

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110855/how-to-set-max-rows-to-textarea-input-tag

Comment: @NikitaSkrebets thanks, i checked https://stackoverflow.com/a/64165303/11856768 demo provided link by you it works well in if i press enter or backspace.
but If I type continuous it goes outside the maximum row (for example more than 5 row) and I see the scrollbar and  how to handle copy paste content?